# Reduce function with simultaneous equations and inequalities

Tags: equation-solving

I have some simultaneous equations that I want to solve, preferably analytically, yet I am unsure if the `Reduce` function is the correct route as it doesn't seem to yield any answers.

The code currently is as follows,

```
expr1 = Cos[η1] Cos[η2] Cos[η3] - Sin[η1] Sin[η3]; 
expr2 = E^(I ϕ1) (Cos[η1]^2 Cos[η2] Cos[2 η3] - Cos[η2] Cos[2 η3] Sin[η1]^2 - 
        2 Cos[η1] (1 + Cos[η2]^2) Cos[η3] Sin[η1] Sin[η3]);
expr3 = 1/2 E^(2 I ϕ1) (1/2 Cos[η1] (-1 + 3 Cos[2 η1]) Cos[η2] Cos[η3] 
        (-1 + 3 Cos[2 η3]) - 6 Cos[η1]^2 Cos[η3]^2 Sin[η1] Sin[η3] - 
        1/2 (1 + 3 Cos[2 η1]) Cos[η2]^2 (1 + 3 Cos[2 η3]) Sin[η1] Sin[η3] + 
        6 Cos[η1] Cos[η2]^3 Cos[η3] Sin[η1]^2 Sin[η3]^2);
```

and the system is,

```
system =  expr1 == a && expr2 == a && expr3 == -a;
```

with conditions,

```
conditions = 0 <= η1 <= 2 Pi && 0 <= η2 <= 2 Pi && 
             0 <= η3 <= 2 Pi && 0 <= ϕ1 <= 2 Pi, 0 <= a <= 1
```

Therefore,

```
sols = Reduce[ system && conditions, {ϕ1, η1, η2, η3, a}, 
               Backsubstitution -> True];
```

I ultimately want to make `expr1 expr2 expr3` more complicated yet I am unsure if this is feasible in *Mathematica*. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks you RunnyKine for the help in reformatting the problem

Comment: You're welcome. Next time you can do it yourself by going [here](http://steampiano.net/msc/)

Comment: I haven't got time for this right now but I suggest you try the following: split the complex equations to real and imaginary parts using `ComplexExpand`, perform `TrigExpand` on the result and substitute algebraic variables for trigonometric ones. It should be easier to solve if you follow these steps (and the equations are consistent)

Comment: Have you tried using the Weierstrass substitution on your equations? This should be easier on `Reduce[]` than the current setup, and you can undo the substitution later to get the angles needed.

Comment: Thank you gpap but unfortunately I didn't have much luck with your approach. Tomorrow I will try J. M. Weierstrass substitution approach and let you know if that helps.